# Add Line Breaks to Mailing Address

Tags: php, html, email

I have a form with a drop down list of shipping address. IMy user selects the desired address from the list and submits the form.
The option in the drop down list is all on one line, like this, which is fine.
**80 Allstate Parkway, Markham, ON, L3R 6H3**

However I need the shipping address that is returned in the form's email to appear stacked like this
**80 Allstate Parkway
Markham, ON
L3R 6H3**

I am running the the mail through an HTML template.

This is the component's code as is:

```
         <label for="shippingaddress">Shipping Address</label><li>
         <li><select id="shipaddress" name="shippingaddress" dir="ltr" lang="en">
         <option selected="selected">80 Allstate Parkway, Markham, ON, L3R 6H3</option>
         <option>30 High Meadow, Toronto, ON, M6L 2Z5</option>
         <option>4000 Victoria Park Avenue, Toronto, ON, M2H 3P4 </option>
         ...
         </select>
```

This is the last hurdle in a long line of hurdles. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code that handles data from the form, thank you.

Comment: Just do a str_replace on the php file that receives the form.

Comment: Hey you guys! Thanks for participating. The form is running through a php file with tons of code in it, I got it from Tectite. What portion do you need to see?

Comment: http://scavanaugh.com/TESTfm.txt

Answer (score 0):

Code that handles data from the form is not shown (yet), but you could use this one:

```
$address = str_replace(",", ",\n", $_POST["shippingaddress"]);
```

Note that this is definitively not the optimal solution, but it should work. It replaces all the commas in the address by comma and new line.

If this doesn't work out for you - as you may be sending the mail as html, you may try instead of using `\n` use `<br>`.

---

After reviewing your code, and for the record, I state that this is not the way it should be done, since it looks like you have no idea what you are doing (at least when speaking PHP).

Try adding:

```
$_POST["shipingaddress"] = str_replace(",", ",\n", $_POST["shippingaddress"]);
```

before this line in your PHP file that you've provided in comment:

```
$aServerVars = &$_SERVER;
```

That should do the trick - and if not, sorry, there's way too much of a code to review. If it does not, I suggest you to get familiar with [PHP](http://php.net/), it's syntax and [string functions](http://php.net/str_replace) (example in link), and ways to [handle form data](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php), to understand what to do to fix this.

Comment: Where in the form handler do I insert that line of PHP (above)?

Comment: @SeanCavanaugh Hard to tell, when I don't see the form handler code... You think I could see it?

Comment: @SeanCavanaugh I think that you are not making it any easier, but I tried my best, it's edited in my answer.